# Video playing on android 2.2 and 2.3 but not on Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, live-streaming

I was developing android application to play live streams. They are working fine on OS 2.2 and 2.3. The new device given to us is OS 4.0.4 and each time I am getting error; Media Error Unknown in the onErrorListener() Method. Here is my code

```
    mVideoView = new VideoView(this);// (VideoView)
    mVideoView.setId(id_mVideoview);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    mVideoView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    mVideoView.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            Toast.makeText(
                    streamplayer_filmstrip.this," Video cannot be        played", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Go_Back();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("VidError",
                        "Exception :: " + e.toString() + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(streamplayer_filmstrip.this,
                        "On Error Ex ::" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    // doneSomething        
                    });


       mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getStreamURL("some_url_for_live_stream")));

        mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(null);
        if (mView1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
        else {
            ll_PopUp.bringToFront();
            mView1.requestFocus();
        }
        mVideoView.start();
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

handling of videos is different in Android based on the device type, you should mention your device and probably the type of streaming you are using, rtsp streaming is supported by android , for other versions your device may or may not support a streaming type.

Comment: Thanks vaibhav. We are testing on android/google TV boxes. This issue is very nerve wrecking. On box with OS 2.2 and 2.3 rtsp streams are playing fine but cease the system on stopPlayback(). On OS 4.0 streams were running with http without ceasing the system on stopPlayback(). They are not playing today however. Do you have any ideas how to deal with support issues?

Comment: One way is to use your own codecs which is very expensive and when I was developing for android streaming problems were varying on every device, from what I remember we used flash in the end which require some changes on server aside from making app unusable on non-flash devices.

Comment: I do think that it has to do with the encoding of stream. If you try link available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131408/android-videoview-live-tv-stream-hls), you will see it runs smoothly (at least on devices I got).