# Android VideoView live tv stream (HLS)

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

I'am trying to develop app for tv streaming (HLS). Using code below I tested stream on 2.3.3, 3.0 and 4.0.1 version Android devices, but encountered several problems. 
On Android 2.3.3 stream plays for >1 minute and then just stops. On Android 3.0 it plays well and on Android 4.0.3 it displays message 'This file cannot be played' (if I remember correctly). 
So my question would be: 
How can I play stream on ether of these devices, without having stream playing problems? Or where can I read more about solutions to these problems (tried to search but found nothing useful)?

Code in Main_Activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView player = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.player);
    String httpLiveUrl = "http://aj.lsops.net/live/aljazeer_en_high.sdp/playlist.m3u8";
    //for Android 2.3.3 I used httplive:// prefix
    player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
    player.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    player.requestFocus();
    player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Code in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if my english is poor.
Thank You.

Comment: Please share how you play live streaming hindi channels ?

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve all the streaming issues. But one thing you should do is call `player.start()` when the MediaPlayer is ready. The selected answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482018/mediaplayer-error-38-0) sets a listener on the MediaPlayer object so that it will run `start()` when `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` is called.

Answer (score -1):

Insert this Code to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```