# mediaPlayer error -38,0

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I try to do simple online radio player. Here is adress of stream http://radio-electron.ru:8000/96 Here is my code.

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example.untitled2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Button playButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                else {
                    try {

                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("http://radio-electron.ru:8000/96"));
                        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i2) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                playButton.setEnabled(false);
                                Log.d("radio", "error " + i + " " + i2);
                                return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                            }
                        });
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("radio", "error " + e);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have no idea, why i get -(38, 0) code and what does it mean.
I using Intellij IDEA and trying this code on Android 2.3 and 4.2 emulators and get some problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

-38 refers to `ENOSYS` error code from [errno.h](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) (see this explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206308/768935)

You seem to try to start the playing before the preparation is complete. Use the  [`setOnPreparedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29) method to set a preparation listener and call the `start()` method only after the preparation is complete.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mp.start();
  }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

And remove the current `mediaPlayer.start()` invocation from the code.

Comment: I get the same error even if I use prepare() method before start(). And prepare() works synchronously. So player should definitely be prepared before start(). It happens only with some files.

Comment: @ka3ak interesting. If you can post it as a question and provide a way to reproduce it, I'm sure there will be someone who can help you.

Comment: I've already found the cause of it. The file path contained #, but I used URL to set the data source. I just wanted to point out that the error can be caused not only by incomplete preparation.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting my `-38` error by calling `getDuration();` on the MediaPlayer *before* it was prepared.

---

It's worth checking the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) doc.

There is a paragraph that starts `It is a programming error to invoke methods such as getCurrentPosition()...`

that has a list of methods which are un-ideal to call before the MediaPlayer is prepared, which in turn may result in `-38`.

Comment: You save my night! Thanks.

Comment: That was happening to me! Both `prepare()` and `start()` calls where OK! Unfortunately, main thread was calling getCurrentPosition() and getDuration() in the wrong moment. I fixed by creating a wrapper class: https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/src-traditional/br/com/carlosrafaelgn/fplay/playback/context/MediaPlayerWrapper.java

Answer (score 3):

You better check if you are executing any operation that is related to the *playing state* like `getCurrentPosition()` before the Mediaplayer is started.

Comment: cool, this was the case for me: I called `mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);` before `onPrepared()` listener was called.

Answer (score 2):

The error code -38 ought to correspond to [`INVALID_OPERATION`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/include/utils/Errors.h?id=refs/heads/ics_chocolate#n45).

A likely cause of this is that you don't wait for `prepareAsync` to finish before you call `start`. You should set an [onPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html) and start the `MediaPlayer` only when `onPrepared` has been called.

Answer (score 2):

@allprog and @Michael are right. But there is another way, if you don't want to use prepareAsync(), use prepare(). That is blocking, which is returned only when it is prepared.