# Can't play MediaPlayer onCreate

Tags: android, media-player, oncreate

I have an app where I want, as soon as it starts, a little background music (opa gangam style!) to be played (from the sd card). I use the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mymusic/gangamstyle.mp3";
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
```

But when I test it, no music is played. I see everything is ok however. What could I do wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: it says Error (-38,0)

Comment: So it doesn't mean anything. Your code is ok.

Comment: for Error (-38,0) checkout this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18482263/3350818)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the media player is ready to play:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(filePath);
player.setVolume(100, 100);
player.setLooping(false);
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mp.start();
    }
});
player.prepare();
```

Comment: tried this and got an error (1, -2147483648). thanks for your help though

Comment: setOnPreparedListener is the key for playing on onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in your file path. Media player gives this kind of error when the file path is not correct. So, Please check your file path and then try it.