# RuntimeException: failure code -38 when MediaPlayer start

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I got a exception when I start MediaPlayer, in most case I think it's an IllegalStateException, but I got RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -38
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:694)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getInbandTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:1944)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:1923)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1205)
```

I have no idea about why this problem occurs, can anyone help about solving this problem? thanks.

This is my code :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getContext().getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                if (player != null)
                    pause();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (player != null)
                    start();       // <-- RuntimeException
                break;
        }
    }
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Where are you calling prepare()?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Have you taken a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482018/mediaplayer-error-38-0/18509212#18509212?

Comment: @GowthamHosamane I called `prepareAsync()` after `setDataSource()`, and I am sure there are no problems around `prepare`. I had viewed the question you posted, and I don't think it's the same question. I got only RuntimeException but he got the `onError()` called because use the `start()` in the wrong state.

Comment: If you have called prepareAsync(), you should have onPreparedListener() Make sure you are calling start() after onPreparedListener() is called. Put some logs to confirm the order.