# E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 64, mPlayer(0x9a024be0)

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to build a basic music player app with only play and stop buttons on it.
Here is the java code

```
**package com.example.android.musicplayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        Button pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song_1);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
           {
               mediaPlayer.start();
           }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}**
```

When I click on play and stop buttons for the first time it works but after that nothing happens.
Here is what looks like on the android monitor when I try to play music again after stop it.

```
05-31 16:05:35.320 31018-31018/com.example.android.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 64, mPlayer(0x9a024be0)

05-31 16:05:35.320 31018-31018/com.example.android.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
05-31 16:05:35.327 31018-31018/com.example.android.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18482263/2784838

Comment: @JunaidHafeez i could not understand that. I am new to android development and trying to learn new topics and ideas.

Answer (score 3):

have a quick look on media player states

[image]

Comment: Well according to the dialgram above we can use the perpare() function after the stop function is called. This will bring the device back to the prepare state.

Answer (score 1):

use this when you click on pause button

```
if (mediaPlayer!= null) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer= null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Simple way to stop the Media Player is :

`if(mediaPlayer!=null)
 {
   mediaPlayer.stop();
   mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}`

[Stop Button Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8d5h.png)